# unable to install pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Swans-MacBook-Pro:~ swan_919$ sudo pip install pandas
The directory '/Users/swan_919/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/swan_919/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Swans-MacBook-Pro:~ swan_919$
```

Hi, I just started learning programming and data science. I had pandas on my previous python version but it wasn't accessible on python 3.6. so at first, i deleted the old pandas files. and tried to install again, but that's basically what happens when i try to do either pip install pandas or sudo pip install pandas. And i can't import pandas either. I would really appreciate the help. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why I was getting all these error messages when I tried the suggested answers. But what ended up working for me is when I just do 'pip3 install pandas'